# Three.js have one particle exactly?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I would like to add just one particle and be able to move it around. However, all I could find it how to do it with a Particle System. I tried adding a particle to the scene as one would do a mesh, but it didn't render. Only when I used a particle system did it render.

Here is what I tried:

```
particle_material = new THREE.ParticleBasicMaterial({ color: 0x0000ff, size: 2000 });
        particle = new THREE.Particle(particle_material);
        particle.position.x = 0;
        particle.position.y = 0;
        particle.position.z = 0;

        scene.add(particle);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`THREE.Particle` is supported by `CanvasRenderer` and `THREE.ParticleSystem` is supported by `WebGLRenderer`.

You may want to consider using `THREE.Sprite`. See http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_sprites.html.

three.js r.60

Comment: Thanks for the sprites suggestion and the insight. I found this to also be helpful: http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Sprites.html